# Find out if type is instantiable

Tags: c#, reflection, interface, types, instantiation

In C#, **how can I find out if a `Type` can be instantiated?**  I am trying to avoid an Activator.CreateInstance exception.

My current method is `type.IsClass && !type.IsInterface`, but I am worried this could fail on abstract classes, etc.  I also considered checking `type.TypeInitializer == null`, but I am not sure if that is foolproof either.

What is the simplest/most efficient way possible to find out if a `Type` is instantiable?

Comment: For it to be "safe" wouldn't he also have to check IsPublic and similar properties on the ConstructorInfo object returned by GetConstructor(). I don't know. I'm asking..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are many other traps.  It could have a constructor that is private or protected.  Or it might not have a default constructor, only constructors that take certain argument types.  If you have to worry about that then you are surely using Activator.CreateInstance() when it should not be used.  Just arbitrarily constructing objects can only create havoc, you have no idea what kind of side effects they may have.  Avoid the "FormatDisk" class.

An exception is your friend, it tells you that your assumptions were wrong.  Never intentionally stop the .NET framework from being helpful.

Comment: I am creating instances of implementations of an interface, so I do know something about them.  I appreciate the warning, though.

Comment: Excellent, then you should not have to worry about exceptions or accidentally creating an abstract class.  A simple well-known name gets the job done.

Comment: How would I go about checking for a default constructor?

Comment: Also, exceptions are good, but so is gracefully handling them.  I would rather check "if (not null)" than "try-catch(null)."

Comment: Accepted for "private constructor" and "non-default constructor" examples.

Answer (score 13):

Consider  [IsAbstract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isabstract.aspx) . It would handle abstract as well as static class. You may also want to check on [IsInterface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isinterface.aspx)

Comment: It seems that IsAbstract is returning true for interface as well: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isabstract(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Don't forget IsGenericTypeDefinition too! Can't create an instance of a generic type with unbound parameters.